# Copy vector<GLubyte> buffer to framebuffer

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-compat

I am trying to avoid using `glDrawPixels` in my code, so I'm looking for an alternative.

Below is the code I'm using to read the framebuffer contents into a `vector<GLubyte>`. Now I need code to transfer the vector contents back to the framebuffer. I've tried a dozen different attempts, but no luck.

```
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);

GLuint copy_tex = 0;
glGenTextures(1, &copy_tex);

vector<GLubyte> tex_buf(4 * win_x * win_y, 0);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, copy_tex);
glCopyTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 0, 0, win_x, win_y, 0);
glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &tex_buf[0]);

for (size_t i = 0; i < win_x; i++)
{
    for (size_t j = 0; j < win_y; j++)
    {
        size_t index = 4 * (i*win_y + j);

        tex_buf[index + 0] = 255;
        tex_buf[index + 1] = 127;
        tex_buf[index + 2] = 0;
    }
}

glDrawPixels(win_x, win_y, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &tex_buf[0]);

glDeleteTextures(1, &copy_tex);
```

Comment: Did you intend for it to all be invisible? You have set the alpha to 0 for each pixel. Try setting `tex_buf[index + 3] = 255;`

Comment: Dear Nathan, thanks for pointing that out. I updated the code on my computer.

Comment: I guess what I should ask is how do I copy from a texture to the framebuffer?

Answer (score 0):

[`glGetTexImage`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetTexImage.xhtml) returns a texture image. If you want to write the image back to the texture then you can use [`glTexSubImage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexSubImage2D.xhtml):

```cpp
glDrawPixels(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, win_x, win_y, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &tex_buf[0]);
```

If you want to  copy a block of pixels from one framebuffer object to another then you can use [`glBlitFramebuffer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBlitFramebuffer.xhtml). For instance copy from a named framebuffer to the default framebuffer:

```cpp
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, my_fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, win_x, win_y, 0, 0, window_h, window_w, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_LINEAR);
```

`window_h`, `window_w` can be different to `win_x`, `win_y` and is the size of the default framebuffer.

Comment: Dear Rabbif76, thank you for your expertise. I've managed to copy from the vector back into GPU memory. Now what I suppose I need is a way to copy from a texture to the framebuffer. I am effectively trying to replace glDrawPixels, as that no longer works on GLFW. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @shawn_halayka You cannot copy from the texture to the framebuffer, because the texture is the color plane of the framebuffer. The framebuffer has no own pixel data. If you want to copy from the named frambuffer to the default framebuffer (the buffer which is shown in the window). Then use `glBlitFramebuffer` as explained in my answer.

Comment: I got it all to work. I ended up drawing to a fullscreen "quad". A source code that was very helpful was: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/progschj/OpenGL-Examples/master/03texture.cpp